# issue of undefined offset in generating referance no

Tags: php, pdf, invoice

i am stuck in a code, which is working fine but not all the time, it works for 4 transactions after that it shows an undefined offset error, which i can not figure out why it is occurring after running for four times, here is the code

```
<?php 
  $Selectlatest=mysqli_query($connection,"Select * from pos_order order by transaction_id desc limit 0,1");
  $row_Selectlatest=mysqli_fetch_array($Selectlatest);

  if(mysqli_num_rows($Selectlatest)==0){
      $num = 001;  
      $invoice_no = date('dmy').$num;
  }

  $new  = str_split($row_Selectlatest['invoice_no'],6);
  $invoice_no= date('dmy').$new[1]+1 ;  

?>
```

it works fine but after 4 consecutive transaction it shows an error which is

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Point_of_sale\admin\cart.php on line 60

How to solve it or any other way of generating the invoice or kind of referance no, which increases after checking the previous number from database?

Comment: Please provide the code. Otherwise no one can help you really.

Comment: i have added the code

Comment: i provided the code when i posted it, for some unknown reason it does not appear